# Call windows function (getting the font directory)

Tags: winapi, go

I try to find out the font folder on a windows installation. AFAICS the proposed way is to call `SHGetKnownFolderPath` in `Shell32.dll` with `KNOWNFOLDERID` set to `FOLDERID_Fonts`.

I have no idea what to pass to the `Call` function in the code below:

```
package main

import (
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    // HRESULT SHGetKnownFolderPath(
    //   _In_      REFKNOWNFOLDERID rfid,
    //   _In_      DWORD dwFlags,
    //   _In_opt_  HANDLE hToken,
    //   _Out_     PWSTR *ppszPath
    // );

    var (
        shell32             = syscall.NewLazyDLL("Shell32.dll")
        shGetKnowFolderPath = shell32.NewProc("SHGetKnownFolderPath")

        // Doesn't work, of course:
        folderId int
        flags    int
        handle   int
        retval   int
    )

    shGetKnowFolderPath.Call(uintptr(folderId), uintptr(flags), uintptr(handle), uintptr(retval))
}
```

Any idea? (I guess a workaround for now would be to stick to `%windir%\Fonts`, but I'd like to get a proper solution).

References:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why the downvote? What can I do to improve the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`golang.org/x/sys/windows` now has a wrapper for `SHGetKnownFolderPath`, so this is much easier:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

func main() {
    path, err := windows.KnownFolderPath(windows.FOLDERID_Fonts, 0)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(path)
}
```

Answer (score 10):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

type GUID struct {
    Data1 uint32
    Data2 uint16
    Data3 uint16
    Data4 [8]byte
}

var (
    FOLDERID_Fonts = GUID{0xFD228CB7, 0xAE11, 0x4AE3, [8]byte{0x86, 0x4C, 0x16, 0xF3, 0x91, 0x0A, 0xB8, 0xFE}}
)

var (
    modShell32               = syscall.NewLazyDLL("Shell32.dll")
    modOle32                 = syscall.NewLazyDLL("Ole32.dll")
    procSHGetKnownFolderPath = modShell32.NewProc("SHGetKnownFolderPath")
    procCoTaskMemFree        = modOle32.NewProc("CoTaskMemFree")
)

func SHGetKnownFolderPath(rfid *GUID, dwFlags uint32, hToken syscall.Handle, pszPath *uintptr) (retval error) {
    r0, _, _ := syscall.Syscall6(procSHGetKnownFolderPath.Addr(), 4, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(rfid)), uintptr(dwFlags), uintptr(hToken), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(pszPath)), 0, 0)
    if r0 != 0 {
        retval = syscall.Errno(r0)
    }
    return
}

func CoTaskMemFree(pv uintptr) {
    syscall.Syscall(procCoTaskMemFree.Addr(), 1, uintptr(pv), 0, 0)
    return
}

func FontFolder() (string, error) {
    var path uintptr
    err := SHGetKnownFolderPath(&FOLDERID_Fonts, 0, 0, &path)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer CoTaskMemFree(path)
    folder := syscall.UTF16ToString((*[1 << 16]uint16)(unsafe.Pointer(path))[:])
    return folder, nil
}

func main() {
    folder, err := FontFolder()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Font Folder:", folder)
}
```

Output:

```
Font Folder: C:\Windows\Fonts
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Still trying to understand this. Give me a day :)

Comment: Nice Answer ... adding just code would not help new developers ... It would be nice for you add details of your process

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone needs the folder id for documents in golang format:

Replace this in peterSO's code example:

```
FOLDERID_Documents = GUID{0xFDD39AD0, 0x238F, 0x46AF, [8]byte{0xAD, 0xB4, 0x6C, 0x85, 0x48, 0x03, 0x69, 0xC7}}

FOLDERID_PublicDocuments = GUID{0xED4824AF, 0xDCE4, 0x45A8, [8]byte{0x81, 0xE2, 0xFC, 0x79, 0x65, 0x08, 0x36, 0x34}}
```

see

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score -1):

`folderId` for the fonts directory is `{FD228CB7-AE11-4AE3-864C-16F3910AB8FE}`

`flags` can probably be `SHGFP_TYPE_DEFAULT`

`handle` can probably be `NULL`

`retval` *I think* should be a `bool` but I'm not sure.

All answers are from your previously linked [SHGetFolderPath function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The return value is of type `HRESULT`. It can be converted to a boolean success code using the macros `SUCCEEDED( hr )` or `FAILED( hr )`.